# Is there on-premise object storage solution compatible with GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, object-storage

I know there's on-premise solution like Minio but I'm not sure it is compatible with GCS.

Is there any on-premise solution which is compatible with GCS client and its protocol? So we can store objects inside on-premise environment and communicate with it by GCS client, when we can't use internet connection.

Or is there way to setup Minio to make it compatible with google storage API, like `google.cloud.storage` python library or `gsutil`, specifically.

I researched about it but I couldn't find good solution.

Comment: I think not. The API belongs to Google Cloud. The underlying file storage system is based on HDFS, but you must change the interface/API to use it.